# How to fix "illegal start of expression try{

Tags: java

I'm trying to have this program read a .csv file and output data after skipping the first line of Strings.

I've tried moving curl brackets or creating a new try-catch block. I've tried moving variables outside the try.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class USCrimesFile{
public static USCrimes[] read(String filename){

    //Declare Array
    USCrimes[] stats = new USCrimes[20];
    //Declare variables
    int count = 0;
    String inFile = "Crime.csv";
    String line;

    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes","unchecked"})

    try
    {
        ArrayList storeList = new ArrayList<USCrimes>();
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;

        //Read file line by line
        strLine = br.readLine();
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) !=null){
            storeList.add(read(strLine));
        }
        in.close();
    }           
    catch (IOException e){          
    }

    try{
        Scanner inputReader;
        inputReader = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        while(inputReader.hasNext()){
            line = inputReader.nextLine();
            String[] data = line.split(",");
            stats[count] = new USCrimes(Integer.parseInt(data[0]));
            stats[count].setPopulation(Double.parseDouble(data[1]));
            stats[count].setMurderRate(Double.parseDouble(data[5]));
            stats[count].setRobberyRate(Double.parseDouble(data[9]));
            count++;
        }
        inputReader.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
    return stats;
}}
```

Expected it to compile but outputted error: illegal start of type
        try

Comment: What is `@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes","unchecked"})` annotating in the code? It's misplaced. Should be removed.

Comment: (In addition to the other comments, I strongly suggest using *try-with-resource*: `try (FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(inFile)) {`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the suppress warning annotation

```
@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes","unchecked"})
```

This should be at the method level or attached to a variable such as `storeList`.

Other problems:

```
catch (IOException e){          
}
```

Never silently swallow exceptions.  If something goes wrong here, you will never know.

```
stats[count] = new USCrimes(Integer.parseInt(data[0]));
```

Check to make sure that the array size is not exceeded - try using an ArrayList

Comment: Annotations can be on local variable declarations too - perhaps the OP's annotation got detached from `storeList`, since `storeList` uses the raw type `ArrayList`.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks, I have updated my answer.  OP please note that resolving this warning would be better than suppressing the warning.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I tried to compile the class again with the -Xlint:unchecked and outputted  warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type ArrayList
    storeList.add(read(strLine));
                 ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class ArrayList.  I am not sure what this means exactly.

Comment: I tried ArrayList<String> storeList = new ArrayList<USCrimes>(); and it didn’t work. Without the string it still gives me illegal start to type try. And it gives me illegal start of type ArrayList<> storeList

Comment: Sorry `ArrayList<USCrimes> storeList = new ArrayList<USCrimes>();`

Comment: Using the ArrayList <USCrimes> it outputs  javac -Xdiags:verbose USCrimesFile.java
USCrimesFile.java:42: error: no suitable method found for add(USCrimes[])
    storeList.add(read(strLine));
             ^
    method ArrayList.add(USCrimes,Object[],int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ArrayList.add(USCrimes) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; USCrimes[] cannot be converted to USCrimes)
    method ArrayList.add(int,USCrimes) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
1 error

Comment: I tried using the try-with-resources and deleting the suppression and still outputted the error in my previous comment.

Comment: Why on earth are you calling your code recursively? `storeList.add(read(strLine));`  - `read` in already the method you are in.  If you don't understand your code, I suggest that you ask a new question, or consult a instructor.  The original question has been answered by me.